# Python script is unable find registry keys value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: python, winreg

I am continuously  facing a problem that my python script is not working on (HKLM: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), i have written a small script in python to search windows registry key values. when i perform searching through CMD it shows the key value that i want, i also noticed that my script works properly on older windows registry vales entries in HKLM but for the new ones it doesn't shows anything.

That's my script written in python to check windows registry values.

```
from winreg import *

key_to_read = input("Enter Path:") #Path: Software\AbcKey
key = input("HKLM or HKCU:") #Hive Name: HKLM\HKCU
if key == 'HKLM':
    a = -2147483646
else:
    a = -2147483647

try:
    aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, a)
    k = OpenKey(aReg, key_to_read)
    print("Registry key value found.")

except:
    print("Nothing found on the given path.")
```

Comment: Did you tried to print out the type of exception and message occurs on the `try` block?

Comment: I'd say that the try/except is hiding the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write keys and values to HKLM hive, then you either have to use a completely different language other than Python, or you have to use some other API other than "winreg", as winreg has a major defect that severely limits what you can do in the Registry, that most other languages have no problem with.

It just fails to make them. It also throws a WinError 5, "access denied", but that is misleading and will only lead you down a dark alley.  You can even configure your account not only as local admin, but full-on "god mode", elevating your account further to system level access, run as part of the operating system, etc., and still no love.

IF it is "permissions", then it is solely in the calls internally to winreg, and / or security flag options that must be passed in -- NOT your actual account permissions or any special environment configuration settings.  However, I have tried every combination (winreg.REG_WRITE / winreg.WIN_ALL_ACCESS / winreg.WIN64, etc), but nothing works when pointed to HKLM hive.  Writing to HKCU is just fine.  Meanwhile, I can manually modify Registy settings in HKLM, or do it with C# and .NET Framework classes, OR C# with dark, unmanaged C# with direct access to Win32 (advapi32.dll), no problem.

I guess Microsoft just happens to be more friendly with their own languages :)

Comment: This answer is just a transcription from a tutorial here:    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdshNIw_ZRM  called:  Updating the windows registry with python (Modify path variable in windows with python)

Comment: Although, after several Google searches, I have not found anything to indicate that this was ever fixed, I will (eventually), look at the change logs directly and request a fix to winreg as appropriate.